# RoR Save current user ID when modifying a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently using the Devise Gem to control user authentication and I want to record the current user ID in a field modified_by of my tables. I have sucessfully recorded the user when creating a record by doing this

```
# POST /weightsets
def create
 @weightset = Weightset.new(weightset_params)
 @weightset.modified_by = current_user

 if @weightset.save
  redirect_to @weightset, notice: 'Weightset was successfully created.'
 else
  render :new
 end
end
```

However when I have tried the same for the update, it doesn't save the user id in the field modified_by

```
def update
 if @weightset.update(weightset_params)
   @weightset.modified_by = current_user  
  redirect_to @weightset, notice: 'Weightset was successfully updated.'
 else
  render :edit
 end
end
```

I am guessing I need to somehow pass the current_user in the params but can't for the life of me figure it out.

Thanks in advance for any help. Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update method you´re just altering the value in memory and not actually persisting it to the DB. The difference here between the create method is that in create you are calling `.save` after you assign the value.

Instead you can pass a block to update which will yield the record before the changes are persisted:

```
def update
  updated = @weightset.update(weightset_params) do |ws|
    ws.modified_by = current_user  
  end 
  if updated
    redirect_to @weightset, notice: 'Weightset was successfully updated.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

You can do the same in your create method to clean it up:

```
# POST /weightsets
def create
  @weightset = Weightset.new(weightset_params) do |ws|
    ws.modified_by = current_user
  end

  if @weightset.save
    redirect_to @weightset, notice: 'Weightset was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Alternatively you can merge `modified_by` into the params as suggested by @Aarthi. But I find using a block preferable as it communicates clearly that you are using a value that is not provided in the parameters.

Comment: Thanks @max for that, when I implemented it worked perfectly - strangely when I did the same for the wirghts, it isn't working
`def update
    
    updated = @weight.update(weight_params) do |w|
      w.modified_by = current_user
    end
    
    if updated
      redirect_to weightset_weight_path(@weightset, @weight), notice: 'Weight was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end`

Comment: apologies I do not seem to get the nack of formatting comments

Comment: That seems like a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can move it to model callback( before save) which will update the column for both create and update or You can just merge the current_user with params itself

```
def weightset_params
params.require(something).permit(something).merge(modified_by: current_user)
end
```

Comment: The part about merging the params is correct but the rest about model callbacks is nonsense since models are not request aware and cannot access the session to get `current_user`